# Spark distinct operation does not work on custom type

Tags: scala, apache-spark, distinct

i'm working with Spark in Scala, and i'm trying to `distinct` an RDD with custom object elements inside.

The distinct operation does not find and "delete" the duplicates and the RDD after the operation is still the same as before.
I can not understand why this is happening. A hint comes to me after i tried to execute the distinct on a RDD of primitives types (and it worked). So i tried to extends `Ordered` in my custom object but nothing new happened.

Following my test code.

```
class AA (val a: Int, val b: Int) extends Ordered[AA] {

    override def toString = "("+a+","+b+")"

    override def equals(t : Any) = t match {
       case that: AA => this.a == that.a & this.b == that.b
       case _ => super.equals(t)
    }

    override def compare(that: AA): Int = { this.b compare that.b }
}
```

The `distinct` operation is here:

```
val par = sc.parallelize[AA](List(new AA(1,2), new AA(2,3), new AA(2,1), new AA(3,2), new AA(3,2)))

println("Count Before: "+par.count())                 // 5
println("Count After: "+par.distinct().count())       // still 5
```

I even tried to compute the distinct using a different flow of execution, using `reduceByKey()` or `aggregateByKey()` but no luck too.

What is happening here?

Thank you in advance to everyone.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to provide `hashCode` as well

```
override def hashCode = (a, b).hashCode
```

Alternatively you can get `equals` and `hashCode` for free by using a case class

Answer (score 0):

You can use `case class` as it comes with `hashCode` and `equals` so `distinct` will work right away:

```
case class AA (val a: Int, val b: Int) {
  override def toString = "("+a+","+b+")"
}
```

Note that it might bug in the Spark REPL: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-2620 but it will work while *actually* executing your job.

Answer (score 0):

When I run your code, I get `java.io.NotSerializableException`.

You don't need to implement `Ordering` and override those methods, just use case classes:

```
import org.apache.spark.{SparkContext, SparkConf}

case class AA (val a: Int, val b: Int)

val conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local").setAppName("example")
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

val par = sc.parallelize[AA](List(AA(1, 2), AA(2, 3), AA(2, 1), AA(3, 2), AA(3, 2)))

println("Count Before: " + par.count()) // 5
println("Count After: " + par.distinct().count()) // 4
```